# Use GPU profiler (for example CodeXL) together with PyOpenCL

Tags: debugging, profile, gpgpu, profiler, pyopencl

I have my complex PyOpenCL app with a lot of buffers creations, kernel templating and etc. I want to profile my app on GPU to see what is the bottle neck in my case.

Is it possible to use some gpu profiler with PyOpenCl app? For example CodeXL.

P.S. I know about event profiling but it isn't enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Look here: http://devgurus.amd.com/message/1282742