# How to use CodeXL to profile pyopencl code?

Tags: python, ide, profiling, opencl, codexl

Is it possible now to use CodeXL or, for that matter, another graphical profiler to monitor execution of OpenCL kernels written for python scripts with pyopencl? I found it possible only to use CodeXL on executable files, which python scripts are not.
If it ends up being important for your answer, all my python modules are installed in an Anaconda environment.

A similar question has already been asked at [Use GPU profiler (for example CodeXL) together with PyOpenCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573338/use-gpu-profiler-for-example-codexl-together-with-pyopencl) , but the answer was presented there as a link that now leads nowhere.

Comment: It should be possible to do it by passing path to python executable and python script as a parameter, for example: `/usr/bin/python my_script.py`

Comment: @doqtor It should be possible, but itactually isn't - for some reason, my project crashes the moment I start debugging because of missing DLL (although all DLLs from the python environment are loaded succesfully).